# I keep receiving error "The request content was malformed: Expected BigDecimal as JsNumber"

Tags: php, json

I am trying to do an API request based on json and one of the parameters i am supplying (10) should be an integer with 2 decimal places but what i have is a whole number. When i do the api call directly as `"amount" => 10.00,` it suceeds but when I hold the integer as `$amount = $received_amount."00";` where `$received_amount = 10;` it throws an error as `Received error response: The request content was malformed: Expected BigDecimal as JsNumber, but got "10.00"`

I have tried most of the methods available changing a whole number by appending 2 decimal places at the end but none seems to work. Any work around?

Comment: PHP automatically converts the type to a String when you append zeros like that. Run the result through `floatval()` before sending to the API. http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is a string construct.  You can't concatenate integers or floats.

`10 . '00'` would give you a string of `'1000'`.  I'm assuming what you meant was `10 . '.00'`.

You can convert an integer to a float in various ways:

```
var_dump(10 + 0.00);
var_dump( (float) 10 );
var_dump( floatval(10) );
```

However, all of these will represent the float as `10` not `10.00` since that is how the float is supposed to be represented in accordance with IEEE754.

The string format is the only way you'll be able to represent `10.00`.  So this comes down to how you send it to Javascript which isn't represented in your question.